# PDO database connection failing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, connection

I have a file that connects to a database. When i ran it on localhost it worked great, but since placing it online the connection fails. My code is;

```
<?php
// List of events
$json = array();

// Query that retrieves events
$requete = "SELECT * FROM rota ORDER BY id";

// connection to the database
try {
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=IllusionsMembers.db.12196899.hostedresource.com;dbname=IllusionsMembers', 'IllusionsMembers', 'password');
} catch(Exception $e) {
exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
// Execute the query
$resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

// sending the encoded result to success page
echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

?>
```

i have a feeling it may be the host name causing errors as i have never used any other name aprt from `localhost` in any other project.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
exit('Unable to connect to database.');
```

To:

```
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit();
```

What message do you get?

**Update 1:**

You need to uncomment: `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` from php.ini and then restart Apache.

Comment: this: `Connection failed: could not find driver`.

Comment: Uncomment extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll from your php.ini and then restart Apache.